# What do you call the "ceiling" of a table?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

In other words, what would you call this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the underside of the table surface (as suggested by the word "ceiling") or the edging (more suggested by the circling on the picture)?

Comment: Some clarifications needed, first as eques asks the underside or the strengthening along the edge.  Next are you looking for a technical term that a professional furniture maker might use, or a common term. Lastly, can you tell us what it is called in your native language.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wording "ceiling" (first time I've ever heard that for a table)   and the hand-drawn circle makes the question,  ambiguous. An arrow might have been clearer; the word "bottom" or "flat top/side/bottom" might have also helped. Could you say why you need to know its name? Context is always useful to know.

Comment: I would suggest you google "parts of a table" and look at the images and articles. That will probably either answer your question or you can come back and clarify what part you are actually referring to.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would simply call it the **[underside](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/underside)** of the table.

> The underside of something is the part of it which normally faces towards the ground.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this picture could help you:[image]

https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/69172544253858594/

Answer (score 9):

This part is called an [apron](https://www.countrysideamishfurniture.com/help/faq/what-is-an-apron). Another name for it is the "skirt" or "skirting".

Comment: Based on the use of "ceiling", I don't think apron is correct. The OP seems to be referring to the underside of the table surface, not the edging.

Comment: @Rompey i think the picture is wrong, you are correct if you just go by the picture, but combining the picture and the title...

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the surface opposite the working surface of the table, we often simply call it "under the table". As in "Jimmy had the bad habit of sticking  his chewing gum under the table".

If you think this is ambiguous and could as easily refer to anywhere under the table, such as the floor under the table, yes it is.

Usually it is obvious from the context what is meant. For example, "the cat is under the table", but if it was, say, a gecko, then it might still be ambiguous, so "the gecko is on the underside of the table" would be better.